# Plus with a bullet in the middle

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

I want to create a symbol "\bulletplus"  which is basically a plus symbol 
with a bullet in middle. The symbol should have the same width and height as 
an usual plus.

[image: bulletplus]

How do I create this using only latex commands? 
(maybe with the help of tikz)

Comment: OOC, what kind of sentential connective is this supposed to be?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Version with scaled down bullet

The following example

- centers the bullet on the plus sign,
- respects the current math style, and
- uses a scaled down version of the bullet, which can be configured by setting macro `\bulletplusscale`.
- The symbol behaves as math binary operator as the plus sign.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\bulletplus}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@bulletplus{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@bulletplus}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused (empty)
  \sbox0{$#1+\m@th$}%
  \sbox2{$#1\vcenter{}$}% math axis
  \rlap{%
    \hbox to \wd0{% centers the bullet in the space of the plus sign.
      \hfil
      % The bullet is moved to the base line, scaled, and
      % moved back.
      \raise\ht2\hbox{%
        \scalebox{\bulletplusscale}{%
          \lower\ht2\hbox{$#1\bullet\m@th$}%
        }%
      }%
      \hfil
    }%
  }%
  +%
}
\newcommand*{\bulletplusscale}{.6}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ A \bulletplus B_{A \bulletplus B_{A \bulletplus B}}\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

---

## Older version with `\bullet` in original size

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\bulletplus}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@bulletplus{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@bulletplus}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused (empty)
  \sbox0{$#1+\m@th$}%
  \rlap{%
    \hbox to \wd0{\hfil$#1\bullet\m@th$\hfil}%
  }%
  +%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ A \bulletplus B_{A \bulletplus B_{A \bulletplus B}}\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Nice but the OP gave an example in which the bullet looks much smaller.

Comment: @Denis Yes, see updated answer (it took some time to implement).

Comment: Quite nice and flexible imhp. Hope the OP likes it.

Answer (score 8):

You can overprint the characters and force the result to be a `\mathbin`, like `+`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}


$\mathbin{+\mathllap{\bullet\mkern2.5mu}}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution with `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass[border = 2pt]{standalone}

 \usepackage{stackengine} %
\newcommand\bullplus{\stackMath\mathbin{\stackinset{c}{0.01ex}{c}{-0.07ex}{\bullet}{+}}}

\begin{document}

 $ x \bullplus y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\bulletplus}{%
\ooalign{$\bullet$\cr\hidewidth$+$\hidewidth}}

\begin{document}

\bulletplus

\end{document}
```

You might want to fine-tune it regarding the bullet's size.