Typesetting custom "accent" or combining characters
I'm trying to make an "accent" that puts a dot in the center of the symbol and another that looks like an 'L' shape that surrounds the bottom left of the symbol.
It should look something like this (the red is the accent part):



Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}. Because you are saying that you are already trying to make this accents, you should be able to show at least what you've tried. BTW: For the dot you could start, e.g., with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336369/277964.

How are you going to use these symbols? As some kind of custom alphabet? Or in a math context? So, should they behave like letters or rather images placed somewhere in a float?

ᐉ ᐅ ᐀ ᐁ ᐂ ᐃ  ᐄᐢ ᐧ ᐱ ᐵ ᑂᒣ ᒥᒩ ᒪ Canadian Syllabics could be used as component source, perhaps. Depends on your purpose and constraints.

Related also on: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263755/creating-a-symbol-that-combines-a-number-with-a-triangle-for-math-mode
